# What causes this? pcieport 0000:00:03.0: PCIe Bus Error: AER / Bad TLP

Tags: hardware, pci

I'm seeing error messages like these below:

```
Nov 15 15:49:52 x99 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:03.0: AER: Multiple 
Corrected error received: id=0018 Nov 15 15:49:52 x99 kernel: pcieport
0000:00:03.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, 
id=0018(Receiver ID) Nov 15 15:49:52 x99 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:03.0: 
device [8086:6f08] error status/mask=00000040/00002000 Nov 15 15:49:52 
x99 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:03.0: [ 6] Bad TLP
```

These will cause degraded performance even though they have (so far) been corrected. Obviously, this issue needs to be resolved. However, I cannot find much about it on the Internet. (Maybe I'm looking in the wrong places.) I found only a few links which I will post below.

Does anyone know more about these errors?

Is it the motherboard, the Samsung 950 Pro, or the GPU (or some combination of these)?

The hardware is: Asus X99 Deluxe II Samsung 950 Pro NVMe in the M2. slot on the mb (which shares PCIe port 3). Nothing else is plugged into PCIe port 3. A GeForce GTX 1070 in PCIe slot 1 Core i7 6850K CPU

A couple of the links I found mentions the same hardware (X99 Deluxe II mb & Samsung950 Pro). I'm running Arch Linux.

I do not find the string "8086:6f08" in journalctl or anywhere else I have thought to search so far.

odd error message with nvme ssd (Bad TLP) : linuxquestions https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/4walnu/odd_error_message_with_nvme_ssd_bad_tlp/

PCIe: Is your card silently struggling with TLP retransmits? http://billauer.co.il/blog/2011/07/pcie-tlp-dllp-retransmit-data-link-layer-error/

GTX 1080 Throwing Bad TLP PCIe Bus Errors - GeForce Forums https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/957456/gtx-1080-throwing-bad-tlp-pcie-bus-errors/

drivers - PCIe error in dmesg log - Ask Ubuntu https://askubuntu.com/questions/643952/pcie-error-in-dmesg-log

780Ti X99 hard lock - PCIE errors - NVIDIA Developer Forums
https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/779994/linux/780ti-x99-hard-lock-pcie-errors/

Comment: i moved my gtx 710 from th pcie x16 slot to a x1 slot (asus prime b450-plus, ryzen 5 3600, samsung nvme 970)

Comment: Useful resources related to this - https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1616364 & https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I can give at least a few details, even though I cannot fully explain what happens.

As described for example [here](http://xillybus.com/tutorials/pci-express-tlp-pcie-primer-tutorial-guide-1), the CPU communicates with the PCIe bus controller by *transaction layer packets* (TLPs). The hardware detects when there are faulty ones, and the Linux kernel reports that as messages.

The kernel option `pci=nommconf` disables Memory-Mapped PCI Configuration Space, which is available in Linux since kernel 2.6. Very roughly, all PCI devices have an area that describe this device (which you see with `lspci -vv`), and the originally method to access this area involves going through I/O ports, while PCIe allows this space to be mapped to memory for simpler access.

That means in this particular case, *something* goes wrong when the PCIe controller uses this method to access the configuraton space of a particular device. It may be a hardware bug in the device, in the PCIe root controller on the motherboard, in the specific interaction of those two, or something else.

By using `pci=nommconf`, the configuration space of all devices will be accessed in the original way, and changing the access methods works around this problem.  So if you want, it's both resolving and suppressing it.

Comment: Can I know if it is my motherboard problem? Or my CPU problem. Should I change them?

Comment: @user2675516: It's not CPU related. It's a problem of the PCIe root controller (which often is in the Southbridge) and/or the PCIe controller of the device, or their interaction. Yes, changing the motherboard for one with different hardware usually gets rid of it.

Comment: I changed from asus e-ws to asus deluxe, but problem still persists. That's why i suspect it is the cpu. Or is it because both are X99 chipset?

Comment: @user2675516: If the chipset is the same, esp. the PCIe controller, then changing the motherboard of course won't help. That's why I wrote "motherboard with **different hardware**".

Comment: the common factor for me seems to be a motherboard with the X99 chipset

Comment: Or, maybe the common factor for me is all Asus motherboards...

Comment: This worked the second time I tried it.  I might have had some driver problems; my advice is if it doesn't work at first, checke that everything is up to date.  Then re-do it.

Comment: Thanks, @dirkt Your pci=nommconf immediately cleared up my identical problem on an HP laptop model 17-bs019dx, https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c05531010 Networking had been working flawlessly on its pre-installed Windows, and under the dual-booting Slackware 14.2x64 that I'd originally installed "alongside" it. But when I replaced 14.2 with Slackware-current64 just the other day, it started throwing all those error messages as soon as dhcpcd started. Couldn't figure out what to do until google coughed up your answer to the problem.

Answer (score 10):

I get the same errors (Bad TLP associated with device 8086:6f08). I have X99 Deluxe II, Samsung 960 pro, Nvidia 1080 ti.  These problems seem to be associated with X99 chipset and M.2 device, like Samsung Pro.

The X99 Deluxe II motherboard shares bandwidth between PCIE16_3 slot and M.2/U.2.  Following comment from @Nic, in the BIOS I changed Onboard Devices Configuration | U.2_2 Bandwidth from Auto to U.2_2.  This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: How did you determine that it is just that chipset? Tried every other chipset? It occurs on a wide variety of hardware.

Comment: @user1759557, thanks for the hint! To fix this for mainboard TUF Z370-PLUS I went to system firmware (AKA "BIOS") configuration: Advanced menu > Onboard Devices Configuration > M.2_1 Configuration, and switched it from [Auto] to [PCIE mode] (I had WD Black SN850 M.2 NVMe SSD installed). Here is the manual page for the reference:
https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1151/TUF_Z370-PLUS_GAMING/E13474_TUF_Z370_PLUS_GAMING_UM_v2_web.pdf#page=75

Comment: PS. OK, I got it slightly wrong: the error occurs from time to time, but it's quite rare – 10 occurrences in an hour (under pretty heave I/O load directed through M.2).

Answer (score 8):

Adding the kernel command line option `pci=nommconf` resolved the issue for me. Therefore, I'm assume the issue is motherboard-related. It happens on ***all*** my X99 motherboard-equipped computers. It does not happen on Z170 systems or any other hardware I own.

Comment: Hi I am also facing this problem. Can I know what pci-nommconf do? Is it just suppressing the problem or resolving the problem?

Comment: Can't confirm - getting the error on z170i, running arch 4.13.12

Comment: @sitilge - thanks for your comment. Which brand/model z170i? My motherboards are Asus. One is X99 Deluxe II

Comment: It is asus z170i pro gaming.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar experience with an Nvidia RTX2070 and a ROG STRIX B450-F GAMING motherboard.
I solved configuring the specific supported PCIe generation type supported by the Nvidia card (GEN 2) in the bios and added this option on kernel boot parameters:

```
pcie_aspm=off
```

as reported on this [site](https://forum.level1techs.com/t/threadripper-pcie-bus-errors/118977/76)

Changing the PCI Generation didn't really solved it but I think could avoid problems.

Comment: Hi @Alex, yes this is true. I had a smiliar problem, `nommconf` wasn't enough for me. When I use the proprietary NVIDIA driver I need to set `pcie_aspm=off` to get rid off the errors, on a Desktop this is no problem because it's not running on battery. Using `pci=noaer` will suppress the warnings solely which could be an option if `pcie_aspm=off` does not work. On a Laptop I would potentially not advise to disable ASPM. Problem can be circumvented by using the nouveau driver if the problematic device has been identified as the NVIDIA GPU via `lspci -vt` and `dmesg`.

Comment: Addition: Also by using `pcie_aspm=off` instead of simply suppressing warnings via `pci=noaer` I have the impression that my system got a lot more responsive, probably because there is no message spam anymore on the bus... Just a guess.

Answer (score 3):

I changed the PCIE16_3 slot Config in Bios on my x99-E to be static set to x8 mode instead of auto that is default for M.2 device support. Works fine now without TLP errors on both of my 1070GTX cards connected via PCIe 1x to 16x extension boards.

I did not use port 16_3 first, moved to that slot to test but still had issues before change in bios. Also changed bsleep setting for all cards to 30 in the miner config.

Before change I had the kernel log spammed with faults.
Also tried to powercycle system before and after change. Seems to be pretty persistent.

Answer (score 2):

Search your motherboard manual for "AER". You can kill the source of the problem by either correcting the specific incompatibility or  disabling AER altogether. Only use this if all the error spam concerns **corrected** errors, otherwise you could be covering up an actual issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this steps:

1. `cp /etc/default/grub ~/Desktop`
2. Edit grub. Add `pci=noaer` at the end of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. Line will be like this:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=noaer"
   ```
3. `sudo cp ~/Desktop/grub /etc/default/`
4. `sudo update-grub`
5. Reboot now

Comment: I applied your solution but instead of `pci=noaer` I used `pci=nommconf` as suggested by @dirkt

Comment: Thanks, pci=noaer fixed my slackware 14.2x64 problem installed on an hp laptop (desktop install didn't exhibit this problem at all)

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a bit? What does this option do and how do you expect it to solve the problem?

Comment: Why would you just not use `sudoedit` for safe editing? -1 for these copy here and there steps are complete nonsense

Comment: `pci=noaer` just disables the Advanced Error Reporting. So you still have those errors, you just don't see them ...