# Pop OS doesn't boot up because of pci-e bus error

Tags: usb, grub, pci

So, today I downloaded the iso file of the new Pop OS 18.04 in order to try it out.

However, after I created a bootable usb, I opened my laptop, and chose to boot from usb, and suddenly I got a kind of loop that says "PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)"

I got this error in the past, and I still get it every time I boot up Ubuntu, or Ubuntu based distros, but it stops after a moment. In this case, it doesn't.

In theory, I could fix this problem, by adding "pci=noaer" to the grub file, but I can't do the same thing here, because I can't install the OS so I don't even have a grub, or a way to access the terminal.

Is there any way I can fix this problem? Or maybe find the grub file on the USB?

EDIT: I am using a 6th generation intel cpu+hd graphics card. 8gb of ram, and 1TB of storage.
I have already asked a question about this error, and I have seen many others ask the same thing, so, adding the line above *will* fix the problem.
Also, my laptop uses BIOS and not UEFI

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error is probably unrelated to the problem. The problem seems to be the live session either not booting at all or not booting graphically. First thing first, please [edit] the question and add hardware specs, namely graphics. Is it UEFI or BIOS?

Comment: @MichaelBay I added the information you asked for. If you want the link to the other question I asked long time ago, I can add it to the question.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Well, the absence of an high-end Nvidia (or AMD) graphics rules out many things. And it's great you're using UEFI mode (as it should be) because it's very easy to add boot parameters just by editing the "Try [some OS]..." entry by pressing "e" to edit. Your desired boot parameter can then be written in the same line where "quiet splash" is.

Comment: @MichaelBay Apparently I was wrong. Sorry. I have two laptops, and the one who has this bug uses BIOS and not UEFI. Is there anything I can do to fix this problem?

Comment: I found the solution [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/327730/158683)

Comment: @user3405291Wow thanks for your help !! I dont acutally need it now, but still, I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Network adapter was producing error in my case.

"03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter"

Solution was to remove the module from kernel with:

sudo modprobe -r rtll8821ae

For explanation how to find module (rtl8821ae) see:

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=305970

tail /var/log/syslog

Comment: Thanks for trying to help :)  Unfortunately I can't verify your answer, since I don't have that laptop no more, but if people reply that it works, I will verify it