# Why is journalctl reporting "PCIe Bus Error" BadTLP and BadDLLP?

Tags: kernel, logs

I am running Fedora 30 64-bit on an AMD Ryzen 2700U and I've noticed that `journalctl` gets a lot of messages about PCI bus errors (all identical).

What might be causing this and what does it mean by BadTLP and BadDLLP?

```
Sep 23 08:50:37 hpenvy13m kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.7: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:00:01.0
Sep 23 08:50:37 hpenvy13m kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.7: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
Sep 23 08:50:37 hpenvy13m kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.7: AER:   device [1022:15d3] error status/mask=000000c0/00006000
Sep 23 08:50:37 hpenvy13m kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.7: AER:    [ 6] BadTLP
Sep 23 08:50:37 hpenvy13m kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.7: AER:    [ 7] BadDLLP
```

Comment: See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/369090/193028) for "Bad TLP" and some discussion. A "DLLP" is a data link layer packet.