# Strange error spontaneously occurring: pcieport, PCIe Bus Error

Tags: pci

I usually have a terminal application running on my Arch Linux system which takes keyboard input and sits waiting. Sometimes an error spontaneously generates output to the terminal which prints past the prompt for my application and reads in three lines:

```
[9632074.286470] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[9632074.291919] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: device [8086:a298] error status/mask=000000001/000020000 [9632074.293586] pcieport
0000:00:1d.0:   [ 0] RxErr
```

It does not interrupt my program; I can still type into my program normally. The error just appears on the screen.

What is going on? Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Did you open that terminal exclusively for running that terminal application, or is there anything running in the background, too? I only ask because error messages from backgrounded applications still print to the console they were opened from, and that may help pinpoint the origin of the messages. The device mentioned is the PCIe root port, so that in itself doesn't help too much ...

Comment: See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/369090/193028).